# How to release a subview immediately when it performs @selector(removeFromSuperviw) in iOS ARC?

Tags: ios

As mentioned by the title.How to release a subview immediately when it performs @selector(removeFromSuperviw) in iOS ARC? It seems that a subview is not released  after [subview removeFromSuperview] which resulting in memory leak.

Comment: set the subview to nil?

Comment: I've tried, it does't seem to work. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not being released by the next draw cycle (a small fraction of a second), then you are retaining it somewhere else, or you have created a retain loop. This is a classic memory leak error in Cocoa, and you will need to find your bug.

Somewhere you have two objects that refer to each other via a strong reference, and one of them needs to be a weak reference (or be removed, or set to nil, or otherwise broken). One likely possibility is a view controller that has as strong reference to this view. It's possible there isn't actually a cycle; it may just be that some other live object just still has a reference.

(Don't over-read this. ARC is not garbage collection. There is no other object that literally "holds" this view. It's just that some object incremented the retain count and nothing has decremented it yet. But newer developers sometimes have an easier time pretending that it's garbage collection that just can't handle retain cycles.)

[Cocoa With Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html) provides a nice introduction to the problem.

Instruments can be a useful tool using the `ObjectAlloc` or `Leaks` instruments, but I often find that a little thought and code searching finds the problem more quickly.

Comment: Problem is solved, thank you very much!  I need to learn more about ARC.